# Key Configurations for iMac's TrackPad not fully recognised by Blender

Tags: interface

I have a trackPad, which I use with the Macbook Pro, and works perfectly in Blender.

But it doesn't work in the iMac.

I installed the latest version 2.78.

and used the same StartUp File.

I exported the Key Configurations.

But, the Keys don't work. Rotation, Move, & Zoom.

I tried the Emulate 3 button mouse, and many other options, such as Middle instead of Trackpad, etc.

In a forum someone said, the problem is between the trackpad and the iMac, so the comunication from the TrackPad doesn't reach Blender.

The trackpad works fine with all other softwares.

So, I decided to reinstall the drivers. but when installing them I got a message saying that I didn't need to reinstall them. And didn't allow me go go further.

In this image you have the configuration that works in the Macbook Pro with the same TrackPad, but not in the iMac.

[image: Blender input Configuration for view3d.zoom]

Any suggestions?

Comment: I still didn't manage to fix this. if anyone has an iMac with a trackpad, that would be nice if I could see your keys configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you work with puzzles, I don't know if this is a piece of the same puzzle or completely different, so I thought I would mention it to see if it helps. I've been using my trackpad with Blender on my SuperMac for a while. Everything was fine. Now, it mostly works, but when I use the 3 finger grab on the arrow to move it along an axis, it goes wacky. I used to be able to grab an axis arrow (not sure what it's called exactly) and move it precisely. Now, just a little move and it goes way far. I haven't changed any settings and replaced the batteries. If I press the "G" and choose and axis to move on, it will work correctly. Just wanted to give more info to see if it works out with anything.